# Re-render view after updating variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a form which will allow for the configuration of a product. For example, you could add a widget and that will cause the price of the product to have *£x* added to it. For example, [Apple's configuration page](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MGX72LL/A&step=config). If you choose a different processor or w/e the price will be updated in the view accordingly.

So I've got a field in my model which contains a base price, and I set the price that gets shown in the view to be the the `base_price + addons[]` .

What I can't figure out is how to update the price in the view when the user changes some configuration setting. I can change the value of the variable, but I don't know how to update what gets shown in the view.

As far as I can tell the embedded Ruby code in the view only gets called on load, so the price that gets shown is always just the original value of the `total_price` variable. I'm guessing I'll need Javascript but is there a provision in Rails for doing something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need a lot of JavaScript to do this. Maybe you could try enhancing your page with [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)?

Comment: @tadman So instead of trying to use variables in Ruby on the backend, I should basically duplicate the data (have two sets of data, one in Ruby and another in Angular reflecting the Ruby variables) and use the Angular variables to update the view?

Comment: HTML is inherently static unless you use JavaScript to manipulate it. Using the [HTML data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) you can usually produce an HTML document with the correct presentation and also include the raw data which JavaScript can use to do calculations. Typically you will need two implementations, one client-side in JavaScript that responds instantly to client changes, and another server-side that makes the final tally before saving to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add the remote: true option to your form, then after the data is sent to the server via ajax and processed in the controller, you can render a view with extension .html.js and inside that view you put some javascript code to update your current view like this:

```
$("#total-price").replaceWith("<%= j(render(partial: 'location', layout: false)) %>");
```

That piece of javascript (that you can enhance with some ruby through erb) is then executed when it is returned to the view after the ajax call.

This is a very powerful tool that rails provides.